# How to read paged records in mongo when record creator is deleted

Tags: mongodb

May be title is not very clear but I'll try to explain.

There are two collections in mongo:

```
groups
users
```

Groups are created by users.

UI sends a */groups/1/10* to read first 10 groups. We don't want to return groups whose creators(users) are deleted.

Example:

UI makes call: */groups/1/10*

Let us say only 8 records are available because 2 users are deleted from the system, hence their groups are not available.

What should we do?

Should UI make another request like:  */groups/1/2* ?

Should we read let's say 20 groups, read first 10 available groups and return them? This may not be very good for second or third pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not enough information here to give a specific answer, specifically we need to know more about the schema that you are using. We'll try to give some general details that might point things in the right direction. We are also assuming that your endpoints are structured as `/groups/<pageNumber>/<pageSize>`.

Broadly speaking, if the client calls `/groups/1/10` and there are (at least) `10` valid matching results, then the system should return `10` results.

It's not clear what you mean when you say:

> only 8 records are available because 2 users are deleted from the system, hence their groups are not available ... Should UI make another request like: /groups/1/2 ?

The first part of that statement implies that there are only `8` valid results, but the second part implies that there are at least `2` more valid results that can be retrieved. If there are `10` valid results then they should be all get returned.

How you accomplish this depends on how invalid `groups` and/or deleted `users` are represented in your system. If, for example, the documents in your `groups` collection have some sort of `valid` field that becomes `false` when the `user` who created it gets deleted, then you should be applying a filter to remove those results such as:

```
db.groups.find({ valid: true }).limit(10)
```

If instead the `groups` have a document that references the `user` who created it, then you may need to do something a bit more complex.  That may be along the lines of doing an aggregation that does a `$lookup` on the `users` collection and then perform a subsequent `$match` to remove the `groups` from the results whose creators have been deleted.

While there are many approaches to this problem, the only one that I would consider incorrect would be to force the client to perform the group validity check and/or force the client to make multiple requests.

Comment: Thanks @user20042973, I think I need to work on $lookup. When user is deleted, we are not changing any field in groups collection.

Comment: Certainly one option would be to consider changing the code to update `groups` when the creator is deleted.  But if you don't do that, then your aggregation might look something like `[ $match, $lookup, $match, <$skip>, $limit ]`. If you are sure that there can only be a maximum of one creator, then you may want to use `$unwind` which would make the pipeline `[ $match, $lookup, $unwind, <$skip>, $limit ]`.